# Is this a Python closure? (or, why does this code work?)

Tags: python, closures

I am wondering why the following Python code works:

```
def sum(a, b):
    return a+b+c
c=3
print sum(1,2)
# result: 6
```

I would have expected an compiling error.
How can the `sum` function already be defined when variable `c` is not (I would say that `c` is not in scope of the sum function) ?

Is this what they call a closure?

As I understood closures, the variable had to be already 'mentioned', like in the following code snippets (copied from [this site](http://ynniv.com/blog/2007/08/closures-in-python.html)). Here the `x` is already mentioned (although not 'filled in') above the definition of the `inc()` function.

```
def makeInc(x):
  def inc(y):
     # x is "closed" in the definition of inc
     return y + x
```

Comment: @BoltClock: Not really. `sum()` doesn't carry any scopes.

Comment: This is not a closure this just how python scoping work

Comment: It might help to understand the difference between compile time and run time. And I doubt it's a closure, when it references global variables. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29#Python

Comment: you should look for the "namespace" concept, and that's not a closure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, `c` is found in the globals table. If you try to call `sum(1,2)` and `c` cannot be found in the function's scope, or it's parent scope (the global scope), then you will get a NameError exception.

Whilst this is similar to a closure, accessing global variables inside a function body is generally frowned upon, as it makes debugging much harder. A better example of a named closure in python (from Wikipedia):

```
def outer():
    y = 0
    def inner():
        nonlocal y
        y += 1
        return y
    return inner

f = outer() 
print(f(), f(), f()) #prints 1 2 3
```

For more details, see the Wikipedia entry on Closures: [Python example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29#Python).

Comment: Strangely enough, `inner` works if the `y = 0` occurs after its definition.

Comment: Omnifarious: Not that strange. Python scopes are mutable.

Comment: Python uses a 2-pass compiler - it sees the outer definition on the first pass, so it knows how to hook it up on the second pass. You would get an exception if you tried to *call* the inner function before the definition of `y` though.

Answer (score 4):

Python would throw an error if a variable is not defined when the function is called.
You call `Sum` when `c` is defined.

Comment: I think it's not. As it was said: this is just how python scoping work

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't evaluate the body of sum until it is called.  Since c is defined before sum is called, it is available to be used by sum.